# Rosyln Analyzer not detecting While Expressions

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn-code-analysis

I have written a small custom Rosyln Analyzer that checks for certain method invocations, and if they were executed within a loop context or expression. An example of the code I am wanting to warn on can be found below:

```cs
IMessageHandlerContext context = default;

foreach (var item in dataItems)
{
    await context.Send<IProcessItem>(m =>
    {
        m.Item = "my-item-id";
    });
}
```

I perform a two-stage analysis by first checking the method invocation is one I am specifically interested in, by looking at the method name. The second change is to look at the wider context, and test if the Invocation happens inside a loop context or expression. The Analyzer works for For and ForEach constructs, but fails to highlight for the While loop expression. I am satisified the first stage, which looks at Method names, is working fine.

```cs
private void CheckForMethodInvocationInLoop(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var invocation = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)context.Node;

    var containsMethod = false;
    // Removed stage one code for brevity

    if (!containsMethod)
        return;

    var loopFound = invocation.FirstAncestorOrSelf<StatementSyntax>(ss => 
        ss.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ForStatement) || 
        ss.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ForEachStatement) || 
        ss.IsKind(SyntaxKind.WhileStatement));

    if (loopFound != null)
    {
        context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, invocation.GetLocation()));
    }
}
```

The Analyzer correctly highlights method invocations within For and ForEach expressions, however does not identify the same invocations in While expressions.

Invocation inside ForEach expression, syntax hightlighting

[image: Invocation inside ForEach expression, syntax hightlighting]

Invocation inside While expression, no syntax highlighting

[image: Invocation inside While expression, no syntax highlighting]

I have tried a couple of techniques to check the invocation context. Firstly, by recursively checking each parent, and it's parent, on the invocation statement. I have also attempted to utilise the method `FirstAncestorOrSelf` on the invocation itself to test for a kind of Statement. By inspecting the Syntax Visualizer I cannot determine why the analyzer cannot identify the invocation inside the While expression.

Comment: Put a minimal analyzer sample on github (ie, that compiles and exhibits the problem) and I'll take a look if you want. Otherwise, it's pretty difficult to guess what the problem is from this.

Comment: No problem at all! I have uploaded the analyzer and a sample project with expected assertions. You can access it on https://github.com/thomasintkylej/custom-rosyln-analyzer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I took a look at your repo and after [fixing a few quick things](https://github.com/thomasintkylej/custom-rosyln-analyzer/pull/1/files) (like the analyzer not being referenced in your main project, or the fact that analyzers have to be build against `netstandard2.0`) the diagnostics worked as expected:

[image: demo]

Comment: Hi Blindy, thanks for taking the time to look at my question. I really appreciate it! I was testing using the Vsix project and opening the Test project I created. However, this approach certainly makes the time-to-test a lot quicker, as I'm no longer debugging VS itself!

The sample I created appears to work with While expressions, and my real source code does too. Possibly, Rosyln had the rule cached and was not refreshing the rule when I was testing. It appears to work now though!

Comment: The intended way to debug analyzers (and source generators) is to debug the compiler, not VS itself with the vsix. I enabled that for you as well (`<IsRoslynComponent>true</IsRoslynComponent>`). And you are mistaking about the cached anything, your analyzer gets called for every single changed without any caching. The problem was that your analyzer was simply throwing an exception due to a missing .net6 library in VS (which is .Net Framework) and wasn't updating the current list of diagnostics.

Comment: Hi, I naively assumed it was not an issue with my code or project setup! Thank you for pointing that out. I am new to writing Rosyln Analyzers, and following the guide and one of the default templates encourage the use of a Vsix project. I am relieved to discover this other technique and am greatly appreciative of your help!